# Can we zoom/scale image in popup using JQUERY library

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, zooming

I have dynaically geneated images which needs to be zoom out/zoom in while do mouse hover.

i tried below way,

```
 .thumbnail_img img:hover
 {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
-moz-transform: scale(1.5);
-o-transform: scale(1.5);
-ms-transform: scale(1.5);
transform: scale(1.5);
```

}

But it just scale the image and image become blur.

tried below way also,

```
    $('#' + '<%=dntbuddata.ClientID%>').hover(function () {
        $(this).css({ width: "430px", height: "434px" });
    }, function () {
        $(this).css({ width: "130", height: "134%" });
    });
}
```

Above way also scale the image and even UI distrub.

It would be great if image ZOOM OUT inpopup dialog and not blur.

As these all images are generated dynaimically, i cna't create two copies and switch between them on mouse over.

Update:

Now, i able to resolve image blur issue thorugh below called as suggestion. Now, How can i open this image into popup dialog  (disable/black backgrouond)?

```
   if ($('#' + '<%=dntbudget.ClientID%>')) {
    $('#' + '<%=dntbudget.ClientID%>').css({ width: "130px", height: "134px", 'max-height': "530px",'max-width': "534px"});

   $('#' + '<%=dntbudget.ClientID%>').hover(function () {
       //$(this).css({ width: "430px", height: "434px" });
       $(this).animate({ width: "530px", height: "534px" }, 'slow');


   }, function () {
       // $(this).css({ width: "130px", height: "134px" });
       $(this).animate({ width: "130px", height: "134px" }, 'slow');
   });
```

Thanks
Dhaval soni

Comment: Well if you wish to zoom, you'll need anyway to generate a higher resolution picture. But indeed you can just generate 1, and just display it smaller on the page. Then you should be able to use any of the magnigying libraries/plugins available out there

Comment: for now, i kept the image with 130px-134px width-height. and zooming through above CSS approach to scale but getting blur.

Comment: you can't expect much quality of a zoom (or enlargement) on a 130/134px picture anyway, that's what I was trying to explain in my previous comment. Also, in your example `$(this).css({ width: "130", height: "134%" });` should be `$(this).css({ width: "130px", height: "134px" });`

Comment: @Bartdude Please find updated question, as you suggested, now able to resolve blur issue. (addionally, i have also set - image - min width/min height and max width and max height). NOw, how i could open this in popup dialog.